# how to create modules inside modules in joomla

Tags: php, joomla

i want to add 4 modules in my footer. after adding my code in index.php

```
<?php if ($view->containsModules('footer1','footer2','footer3')) : ?>
                <?php echo $view->positions(array('footer1' => 33, 'footer2' => 33, 'footer3' => 34), 'pkt-nostyle'); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

my modules look like this:

http://s21.postimg.org/iisnlopkn/image.jpg (sorry i cant post img here cause i dnt have enough reputation)

but i want my modules like this:

http://s23.postimg.org/kd6f61sfv/image.jpg

any help out there?? i will put other necessary code in the templateDetails.xml and other files. i just dont know the way of creating 2 rows in a single column. any type of help would be appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include your four modules positions within your template's index.php by using code like,

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="name of module position" style="xhtml" />
```

http://docs.joomla.org/Declaring_module_positions

While adding these positions wrap them in required html elements in order to achieve the desired layout with the help of css that you will include in your template's style sheets.

rough example,

HTML

```
<div>
    <div class="mod1 mod side">1</div>
    <div class="mod2 mod side">2</div>
    <div class="container mod side">
    <div class="mod3 mod">3</div>
    <div class="mod4 mod">4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.mod{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border: 1px solid dimgrey;
}
.side {
    float:left;
}
.mod3{
    height:48px;
}
.mod4{
    height:48px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KbVMw/

Then add your modules to the corresponding positions.